# Web app service in Azure restarts many times a day without error in logs

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am running an ASP .Net Web API 2 application in an Azure Web App Service.

Many times a day (5-6 times), the Web Service restarts without any earlier notice or error message. I scaled to two instances (always, does not depend on load) and both get restarted simultaneously.

I did set the "Always-On" (keep-alive) setting and I can see successful requests being performed a few seconds or minutes before the Web Service restarts.

When it does restart it always restarts twice, the second time I get the following error in the logs (same error appears a few times, every 10sec):

```
Could not send heartbeat. Access to the path 
'C:\DWASFiles\Sites\#1mysite\VirtualDirectory0\data\DaaS\Heartbeats\RD000F3D11DC6C' 
is denied.
```

This error message is *sometimes* followed by the following:

```
Terminating RD000F3D10A5B7. 1/15/2016 6:16:45 AM vs (now) 1/15/2016 6:38:08 AM
Couldn't delete exception RD000F3D10A5B7. One or more errors occurred.
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
at DaaS.HeartBeats.HeartBeat.Delete()

Terminating RD000F3D11DC6C. 1/15/2016 6:16:38 AM vs (now) 1/15/2016 6:38:08 AM
Couldn't delete exception RD000F3D11DC6C. One or more errors occurred.
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
at DaaS.HeartBeats.HeartBeat.Delete()
Thread was being aborted.
```

Which is probably the cause of the second restart.

Notice that the `Could not send heartbeat` error only concerns one instance but both get restarted.

I sometimes get the `Could not send heartbeat` message without having my instance restarted.

I already had this error when I scaled to only one instance.

My Web Service logs both to an SQL Database and to a Blob Storage and I cannot see any error message that explains the first restart. The error messages i produced earlier were caught by the Blob Storage. There is no message in the Event Viewer either.

Has anyone stumbled upon this issue?

Comment: Do you remember how long you've been seeing this? These error messages indicate that either the VMs hosting your web app are being restarted, or that the file servers serving your content are being restarted. This might happen occassionally, but is not expected multiple times a day.

Comment: Can you share your Web App name, either directly or [indirectly](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly)? This will help us investigate. Also, please include the UTC time of one such incident. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisGillum It's hard to say, from my logs I can see whenever the webapp restarted but sometimes it might have been when I initiated the restart (deploy, change config or manual restart). I don't work at night though so looking at the days where a few restarts happened during the night i can say that the issue started on January 6th or 7th and became more frequent on January 12th. Funnily enough, the issue hasn't happened since 2016-01-15 06:37 UTC

Comment: @DavidEbbo Sure. I can't find any way to send private messages on SO so i can give it here. The web app name is "liuappproxy" and the latest occurence is around 2016-01-15 06:37:21 UTC (or a bit earlier, this timestamp is the one of the first restart). Funnily enough the issue hasn't happened since then, so I have just had 72hours without restarts.

Comment: I'd say let's wait to see if it happens again. If it does, please report the time here. Note that once or twice on some days is normal during system upgrades. But many times a day is not.

Comment: @DavidEbbo The issue seems to have happened a couple of times yesterday. Unfortunately I don't have logs for yesterday, the following happened to me: I had blob storage running for more than a week. I just went into the portal to show something to a colleague 2016-01-18 08:28 UTC and blob logging turned off by itself. I will put it back on and come back to you when I have more error instances that I can identify with the logs.