# Azure Websites frequent short outages

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

MVC5 starter app deployed to Azure Websites, Standard tier, 2 small instances, AlwaysOn configured. Using New Relic's Availability monitoring to see uptime.

Over the course of 2 days the application was considered down on 8 occasions, ranging from 2-8 minutes.

Have you experienced similar issues with Azure Websites? Are there some options I haven't yet discovered that could help reduce these small outages?

Comment: I did. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808829/web-app-service-in-azure-restarts-many-times-a-day-without-error-in-logs but things have been working without interruption since 2016-01-15 07:00 UTC

Comment: I'm also seeing this with my Azure Web Apps. I'm running a NodeJS App with two Web Jobs and I'm using 2 instances as well. I hoped to decrease the downtime between automatic server migrations that Azure seems to carry out automatically by using two instances, but apparently this does not help incoming requests from failing. The Response Time goes up during these migrations and I'm still not sure why this is happening.

Comment: We got a response from the Azure team. It appears that they have to do  a self-heal from time to time and this results in a WebSite restart. Note that these are different from self-heals that can be configured by you, they happen out of your control. Hopefully there is some connection draining. From my experience these self-heals that we have no control over happen daily. This feature/bug is not mentioned anywhere in the docs either, it would be nice if MS be open about these short-comings. The problem can be mitigated by having a fast startup time.